# Import libphonenumber in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I'm using the Eclipse SDK to develope some Android projects. Now I've the following problem:

I want to use Google's libphonenumer library. I've just downloaded it here: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

I've copied the whole java folder on my disk and now I want to import it into my Eclipse workspace. Problem is: Eclipse can't find any project there, so import doesn't work. Also the option "Import from existing code" isn't working.

How can I import `libphonenumber` library code into my Eclipse workspace?

Answer (score -1):

Moving to "tools/java/java-build/target" and importing the contained archive worked for me.